# Explain the Javascript code, pad to left or rightside of string

Tags: javascript

I am learning Javascript and trying to do some challenges on codewar. I have the code for a challenge and I am trying to understand the logic.

The code snippet of interest is the function `padIt`, which accepts 2 parameters:

1. `str` - a string we need to pad with `"*"` at the left or rightside
2. `n` - a number representing how many times we will pad the string.

My question is, why do they use `n--` and not `n++`?

```
function padIt(str, n) {
    while(n>0) {
        if(n%2 === 0) {
            str = str + "*";
        }
        else{
            str = "*" + str;
        }
        n --;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you have a choice between counting up to some semi-random number, or counting down to zero, the latter is usually a fraction faster.

Comment: Incidentally, this function appears to be intended to pad boths sides equally, not left _or_ right as your question suggests.

Answer (score 1):

if you use n++ the while loop will never end since it is checking if n is larger than 0

imagine n is 3: n will be 4,5,6,7,8 then it is a infinite while loop

instead n represent how many times to pad the string so if you want to add 3 * n will go down from 3 to 2 to 1 and the while loop will end

Answer (score 0):

> Why `n--` and not `n++`?

First of all notice the condition of `while` loop `n>0`. It means keep executing the while block. Means keep padding the string until `n` is greater than `0`. Initially `n` is always greater than `1`. So we need to decrease is in order to end the while loop.

If we use `n++` instead of `n--` the code will create infinite loop