# How to use getMilliseconds() and get value in 3 digits always?

Tags: javascript, time

Can you please let me know how to make sure that the milliseconds are always a 3 digit number.
My code is currently giving the output of a three digit number only when the value of milisecs is 2 digit like "099" and if 1 digit I get this "0009" can you please solve this.

Js here

```
function time(){
var findDate=new Date();
var year=findDate.getFullYear() 
var findMonth=findDate.getMonth()
Var month=findMonth+1,day=findDate.getDate();
var hour=findDate.getHours()
var mins=findDate.getMinutes()
var second=findDa    te.getSeconds()
var milisec=findDate.getMilliseconds(),b="/",c=":";
if(day<10){day="0"+day} 
if(month<10){month="0"+month}
if(hour<10){hour="0"+hour}
if(mins<10){mins="0"+mins}
if(second<10){second="0"+second}
if(milisec<100){milisec="0"+milisec}
if(milisec<10){milisec="00"+milisec}
var date="Date="+day+b+month+b+year+" Time="+hour+c+mins+c+second+"."+milisec;
document.getElementById('time').innerHTML=date}
```

Html

```
<button class="time" type="button" onclick="time()">
What is the Date and Time?</button>
<p id="time" class="p" ></p>
```

.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Explain the Javascript code, pad to left or rightside of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56938194/explain-the-javascript-code-pad-to-left-or-rightside-of-string)

Comment: Simply use `String(milisec).padStart(3, "0")`.

Comment: Where do I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure you always get last 3 digits of a string, you can use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) function.

```
const milliSec = findDate.getMilliseconds();
const formattedMilliSec = `00${milliSec}`.slice(-3);
console.log(formattedMilliSec)
```

Comment: Are you using jquery cause I don't use it

Comment: There is not Jquery in this code

Comment: It's saying that slice is not a function

Comment: Hi I found an answer to the problem. Instead of me adding `if(milliseconds<10){milisec="00"+milisec}` I should have used `if(milliseconds<10){milisec="0"+milisec}`  this would solve my problem of getting a value of `0009` if the milliseconds was of only 1 digit.  *Thanks* for the help but I got my own answer.

Comment: The `if` functions used to run at the same time causing an extra`0` so if each `if` function added a `0` they would sum up to `00` when I had only 1 digit in milliseconds.